# Avoiding Functions() in the Where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, collation

Okay, while analyzing queries against a **SQL Server 2008 R2** database, I happened upon the following query:

```
(@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)) 
SELECT TOP (1) [Extent1].[OrderSOId] AS [OrderSOId], [Extent1] 
   .[WarehouseId] AS [WarehouseId], [Extent1] 
   .[MemberId] AS [MemberId], [Extent1] 
   .[ShipmentMethod] AS [ShipmentMethod], [Extent1] 
   .[PaymentMethod] AS [PaymentMethod], [Extent1] 
   .[CustomerName] AS [CustomerName], [Extent1] 
   .[Status] AS [Status], [Extent1] 
   .[OrderSONo] AS [OrderSONo], [Extent1] 
   .[OrderSODate] AS [OrderSODate], [Extent1] 
   .[OrderType] AS [OrderType], [Extent1] 
   .[DeliveryTo] AS [DeliveryTo], [Extent1] 
   .[DeliveryAddress] AS [DeliveryAddress], [Extent1] 
   .[DeliveryAddress2] AS [DeliveryAddress2], [Extent1] 
   .[DeliveryPostal] AS [DeliveryPostal], [Extent1] 
   .[DeliveryCity] AS [DeliveryCity], [Extent1] 
   .[DeliveryState] AS [DeliveryState], [Extent1] 
   .[DeliveryCountry] AS [DeliveryCountry], [Extent1] 
   .[Remarks] AS [Remarks], [Extent1] 
   .[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Extent1] 
   .[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Extent1] 
   .[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Extent1] 
   .[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], [Extent1] 
   .[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Extent1] 
   .[Total] AS [Total], [Extent1] 
   .[AppId] AS [AppId], [Extent1] 
   .[DiscountType] AS [DiscountType], [Extent1] 
   .[DiscountAmount] AS [DiscountAmount], [Extent1] 
   .[isPrepared] AS [isPrepared], [Extent1] 
   .[ExternalRefId] AS [ExternalRefId], [Extent1] 
   .[DeliveryEmail] AS [DeliveryEmail]  
FROM [dbo].[OrderSO] AS [Extent1]  
WHERE ([Extent1].[IsDeleted] <> cast(1 as bit))  
AND ((LTRIM(RTRIM(LOWER([Extent1].[OrderSONo])))) = (LTRIM(RTRIM(LOWER(@p__linq__0)))))
```

Ignoring the strange way the SELECT and FROM clauses are generated, I am more concerned with the WHERE clause, because it uses functions to provide whitespace trimming and case insensitivity. According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940750/149900), using such functions in the WHERE clause will "...will generally preclude the use of an index..."

I know that the `LOWER()` function could be removed by ensuring that collation is `_CI_` (which it *is*, for the DB in question). How should I remove the `LTRIM(RTRIM())` functions?

Comment: By trimming whitespace from the column (updating once) and then not letting any more whitespace to pass through?

Comment: @ypercube agree, should be that way, but unfortunately I'm not the dev... just an infra guy that has to clean up the mess the devs left...

Comment: Function-based index?

Comment: @Colin'tHart well, SQL Server does not support function-based index, but thanks to your hint, I found [this article](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/function_based_indexes). It said that SQL Server supports _computed columns_, on which indexing can be performed. I'll do some experiments on a 'play table'. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I was going to suggest a virtual column (Oracle terminology for computed column) next!

Comment: Does the data actually have whitespace?  This kind of anti-pattern is fairly common from devs who are trying to "do the right thing" to ensure the code works as expected.  *Perhaps* none of the data actually has whitespace and the `LTRIM(RTRIM(LOWER(` code can simply be removed?

Comment: This query reeks of coming from an ORM like Entity Framework, and perhaps you have no control over the actual query generated.  Just a thought.

Comment: @MaxVernon Yup, you're right about Entity Framework. The analysis tool identified the culprit for this query as EF. I'll have the devs double check on whether the generated query is 'tunable'.

Comment: Trailing white space is ignored for comparison in the SQL standard i.e. `'words'` and `'words   '` are equal.